Launching Windows apps from WSL2 with foreground process control
I'm using WSL2 on Windows 11 and I'm trying to achieve the following: I want to launch Windows applications from within WSL2 and have the Bash terminal maintain a handle to the new process. Specifically, I want to be able to quit the Windows app by pressing CTRL-C in the WSL2 terminal.
For example, when I run mpv.exe from inside WSL2, I want to be able to terminate the mpv.exe process by pressing CTRL-C. Essentially, I want to keep the process in the foreground in the CLI.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this? I'd appreciate any help.

How do you start the application? When you run sleep 3 you can see that bash default behavior is waiting, like you want it to. If you see something different it is probably because the application specifically and intentionally evades it.

What research have you done regarding this and what have you tried so far?
